# How to create uilabel dynamically according to array coming from API.?

Tags: ios, api, dynamic, uilabel

> i need to create uilabel dynamically according to length of array coming from web service. please look at my web service structure.

```
{"result":"Successful","data":[{"price":"100.00","packs":"Bio Bags","pack_id":"1","products":[{"quantity":"15","image":"1454651885ECOWGBS_03.jpg"},{"quantity":"15","image":"1454652017ECOWGBM_03.jpg"},{"quantity":"15","image":"1454652132ECOWGBL_02.jpg"}]},{"price":"200.00","packs":"Party Pack","pack_id":"2","products":[{"quantity":"50","image":"1454589144USI_6819.jpg"},{"quantity":"50","image":"1454587252ecow240b_01.jpg"},{"quantity":"50","image":"1454499020ecow10rp_01.jpg"}]},{"price":"300.00","packs":"Travel Pack","pack_id":"3","products":[{"quantity":"25","image":"1454589144USI_6819.jpg"},{"quantity":"25","image":"1454588615ecow103crp_01.jpg"},{"quantity":"25","image":"1454588259ecowclam_01.jpg"}]},{"price":"400.00","packs":"Kids Pack","pack_id":"4","products":[{"quantity":"25","image":"1454499251ecow6rp_01.jpg"},{"quantity":"25","image":"1454588417ecow5ct_01.jpg"},{"quantity":"25","image":"1454587802ecow340b_01.jpg"}]}]}
```

> i need to set quantity name  and image on uilabel and uiimage as well in uicollectionview cell.sometime quantity name can be 3 sometime it can be 20. Write now i am add it to stoically. please look at my code below.

```
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
```

{
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
    NSArray *dataarray = [[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil]objectForKey:@"data"];

```
[packdetail removeAllObjects];


for (NSDictionary *tmp in dataarray)
{
    NSMutableDictionary *temp = [NSMutableDictionary new];
    [temp setObject:[tmp objectForKey:@"packs"] forKey:@"packs"];
    [temp setObject:[tmp objectForKey:@"pack_id"] forKey:@"pack_id"];

    [packdetail addObject:temp];

    NSArray *productarray = [tmp objectForKey:@"products"];
    NSLog(@"products %@", productarray);

    for (NSDictionary *product in productarray) {

        NSMutableDictionary *temp2 =[NSMutableDictionary new];
        [temp2 setObject:[product objectForKey:@"quantity"]forKey:@"quantity"];
         NSLog(@"temp2 %@", temp2);

        [quantity addObject:temp2];
    }


}
if (packdetail)
{
    [_subscriptioncollectionview reloadData];
          }


      }














  - (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView  numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section{

return [packdetail count];
    }

   -(UICollectionViewCell*)collectionView:(UICollectionView  *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

     SubscriptionCell *cell = (SubscriptionCell*)[collectionView  dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];



cell.packname.text = [[packdetail objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"packs"];
cell.productname.text = [[quantity objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"quantity"];



return cell;

  }
```

> Just give me some basic idea so i can move forward.

Comment: your question is not in clear, in which place u want to create the label

Comment: does your label expand to its content in the array ?

Comment: i need to place uilabel inside uicollectionviewcell

Comment: should i create for loop and create label according to array>

Comment: You have to
- put a UILabel inside your cell, make an IBOulet
- return your array size in the - (NSInteger)numberOfItemsInSection:
- Set your label text from your data array in the - (nullable UICollectionViewCell *)cellForItemAtIndexPath: